# Micro symbol from siunitx disappearing after changing from fontspec to mathspec (XeLaTeX)

Tags: xetex, siunitx, mathspec

Like what the title says, if I use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\SI{5}{\um}
\end{document}
```

I would end up with `5µm`. But changing `\usepackage{fontspec}` to `\usepackage{mathspec}` would result in it becoming `5m`. What's happening? I was under the impression that mathspec is basically fontspec with support for math. Also, moving `\usepackage{siunitx}` before mathspec does not fix this.

Comment: As mentioned in the duplicate, add `\sisetup{math-micro=\text{µ},text-micro=µ}` after loading `siunitx` when you are using `mathspec`.

Comment: As far as I recall ```mathspec``` does _not_ use ```unicode-math```

Comment: @HenriMenke That fixed the problem, thanks! But what about other symbols like Ω (has same problem with the micro-symbol)? I tried using `math-omega=\text{Ω}, text-omega=Ω` but it didn't work as I thought it should.

Edit: changing it to `math-ohm=\text{Ω}, text-ohm=Ω` worked.